# Momentum uncertainty for a free particle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, momentum, wavefunction, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

Free particle is in state psi k, where k is the wavenumber. Now i am trying to findout uncertainty in its momentum. I know that for free particle position is uncertain (delta x approaches to infinity) so by uncertainty principle, uncertainty in my momentum should be zero. But further i know that momentum is hk/2π. So, i am confused about my wavenumber k. Will it vary in this state psi k or in psi k it will be certain?? Bcz change in k (delta k) will make my momentum uncertain.

Comment: Barring the fact that this state is not physical, if you know for sure that your state has momentum $\hbar k$, then why do you think there should be uncertainty?

Comment: Please, use laTex notation for formulae. It's about writing them in between of dollar symbols, and laTex commands inside. See here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: I know the momentum for free particle in gereral. Just i want to know that can k (wave number)  cause uncertainty in momentum for a free particle

Comment: You just *fixed* the momentum to *k*, so it is not uncertain, at all, no?

Answer (score 2):

Mathematically, the argument goes like this: your wave function is
$$\psi_k(x) = e^{ikx}.$$
Note that this is an eigenstate of the momentum operator, since
$$ \hat{p}\psi_k(x) = \frac{\hbar}{i}\frac{d}{dx}\psi_k(x) = \hbar k \psi_k(x).$$
So, the particle has the definite momentum $\hbar k$.

The momentum uncertainty is
$$ \Delta p = \sqrt{\langle p^2\rangle-\langle p\rangle^2}.$$
Now,
$$ \langle p\rangle = \hbar k$$
and
$$ \langle p^2\rangle = \hbar^2k^2, $$
so 
$$ \Delta p = 0 ,$$
as we expected intuitively. You see that this argument easily generalizes: if a state is an eigenstate of the quantum mechanical operator of a physical variable, then the physical variable'a value is the eigenvalue and the uncertainty about it is zero.